# Intel Core i7-9700K vs 9750H

Tags: processor, intel

I'm going to build a computer, but I'm stuck on choosing a processor. I found two processors: Intel Core i7-9700K and i7-9750H. The 9750H, according to the official site, is a bit faster and has more threads. But, on Intel's website it's marked as `Mobile`. Does that mean it's incompatible or it's not recommended to use it in a desktop computer? If that's the case, can 9700K fill up like everything from gaming through 3D animation to programming?

Comment: the 9750H is a CPU only found on laptops, that's why it's meant as "mobile", go with the 9700k

Comment: Why build an Intel system nowadays? Was the price lowered significantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 9750H is a mobile processor, meant to be soldered to a laptop motherboard. It will not fit in a a desktop motherboard, nor will you be able to buy one. So for a desktop you don't have a choice. Unless you buy a notebook.

That said, why would you buy the 9700K now? According to [benchmarks](https://www.anandtech.com/bench/product/2258?vs=2520) the cheaper Ryzen 7 3700X is slightly slower in some tasks (single or light threading),  but can be significantly faster in others (heavily threaded).

That said, what you mostly care about, both for games *and* 3D is single core performance and the GPU. Games tend to be lightly threaded, same as mesh editing. For programming it depends on your language, although I suppose build in any language are paralleled nowadays. Autocompletion in the IDE is more of a single thread stuff as well.

As a side note - you definitely want an RTX. With both Blender and V-Ray supporting RTX it's a no-brainer as long as you have the budget. I've seen benchmarks where Blender render times were cut in half using hardware RT vs pure CUDA on the same card.